# Double letter assignation on USB drive

Tags: windows-11

When i open Explorer (Win 11, 22H2) i see my c:\drive as (C:)  but also see my external SSD drive but as " (E) (E:) " drive and there is no way to correct this. If i go in "Manage",to try to correct this and remove the extra letter,i end up having my external drive showing up as (E) ,with no ":" in there in manage disk but not showing up in Explorer.
Since my Lightroom backup catalog and my RAW photos are there,i'm looking for a way to solve this

Comment: Screenshots will be helpful; please [edit] the question and add them (links to screenshots are fine). Is this `(E)` a label maybe? Does its existence cause any technical problem? Or is the question about aesthetics only?

Comment: Here is a screen shot:

Comment: Well-known setting: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-duplicae-drive-letter-entry-explorer

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I don't think that is the OPs issue.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Some screen shots of your issue would help us understand your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.